# trying to getAllCountries as xml returns 406 not acceptable

Tags: java, xml, spring, rest, maven

I have written a simple web service where I have been able to return json  from the database values successfully and at this point I am trying to return the database values as xml from the database but getting 406 not acceptable. This is my honest attempt:

**controller snippets**

```
@RestController
public class CountryController {

    @Autowired
    CountryService countryService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getAllCountries", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/xml")
    public List<Country> getCountries() {

        List<Country> listOfCountries = countryService.getAllCountries();
        return listOfCountries;
    }
```

**this is my pojo class snippets**

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Country")
@Entity
@Table(name="COUNTRY")
public class Country{

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    int id;

    @Column(name="countryName")
    String countryName; 

    @Column(name="population")
    long population;

    public Country() {
        super();
    }
```

a snippet of pom.xml showing dependent libraries I am using for the serialization to retrieve xml data

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
```

**EDITTED TO SHOW XML CONFIG FILE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

On attempting the above using a rest client returns 406 not acceptable. Kindly assist.

Comment: use @ResponseBody annotation after your Mapping annotation

Comment: also did you use <mvc:annotation-driven/>  its supports convert object to/from XML file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Enable `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` in your spring
   configuration. it supports convert object to/from XML file.
2. Use @ResponseBody after @RequestMapping. @ResponseBody annotations are used to bind the HTTP request/response body with a domain object in method parameter or return type.

Comment: The prefix "mvc" for element "mvc:annotation-driven" is not bound.

Comment: I am having that issue

Comment: @Kingston are you using xml config or java?

Comment: @Kingston if you are using xml config, may i see your config file

Comment: xml config for the app

Comment: @Kingston show us your xml config file this might be your IDE bug.

Comment: @Kingston try to add xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" - to your xml config and clean build your project

Comment: what about this added already >>>>>>
beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"

Comment: @Kingston then remove mvc:annotation-driven and try adding this <annotation-driven />

Comment: SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet spring
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlFactory